# "Cross origin requests" error when loading local file in chrome but in firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

I was trying to load a local json file using `d3.json` method, but I am getting an `error`.

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

But if I load the same in `mozilla firefox`, it runs perfectly fine. My code is:

```
d3.json("some_local_file.json", function(e, data) {
    if (e) console.warn(e) // getting this in chrome
    // rest of the code which is executing in firefox
}
```

Chrome Version is : `59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Firefox Version is: `52.0.2 (64-bit)`

I am not able to understand that if I am making some mistake or it is related to browser. Please help me to understand this.

Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: chrome treats file:/// accessing file:/// as cross origin because Chrome - you need command line switch `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for quick response. Can you add how to include `--allow-file-access-from-files` in mac? How to run chrome with this switch?

Comment: google *allow-file-access-from-files mac chrome*